# What does DACPAC stand for?

Tags: visual-studio, compilation, sql-server-data-tools, dacpac

In Visual Studio 2012 we have new project type called `SQL Server Database Project` and when compiled will create a .dacpac output file.

A Google for this term will link it with `Data-tier Application` but I cannot link this name with D A C P A and C?

What does `dacpac` stand for?

Comment: I think `DAC package`! have a look [Data-tier Applications](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210546.aspx)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff678491%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#build

Comment: @duMpty Please make your comment an answer to get accepted. DAC stands for Data-tier application would make more sense

Comment: The nonsensical part is that DAC stands for Data-tier Application.  Various unauthoritative sources claim this abbreviation was chosen because DTA was already reserved to refer to the Database Engine Tuning Advisor.

Comment: @Brian according to MS that's not quite right, they say 

"You can “birth” a Data Tier Application in two places. <snip> 
In both cases, something called a DAC – or Data Application Component – is created. It’s a file with the payload of the the major parts of the structure of the database and so on. that’s the “package” you use to transfer the DTA around.".  

More on that and the reuse of acronyms in my answer below.

Answer (score 20):

In the article ['It’s Data Tier Application and Data Application Component' from December 23 2009](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/buckwoody/2009/12/23/its-data-tier-application-and-data-application-component/) Microsoft's Buck Woody states DAC stands for:

- **D**ata **A**pplication **C**omponent

And he also talks about the result as a package, so it seems reasonable to surmise:

- The **PAC** part probably refers to **pac**kage.

This is the relevant quote (relevant part in bold, my emphasis):

> OK – In SQL Server 2008 R2 we did “re-use” an acronym or two (DAC and
> DTA), but it’s important to remember there are actually two parts to
> this new feature. One is the Data Application Component (DAC) and the
> other is the Data Tier Application (DTA). The DAC is the file created
> for a DTA.
>
> In SQL Server 2008R2 and Visual Studio you’ll find there is a new way
> to write and transfer database code. I’ll blog about it more as I
> finish my testing, but the process works kind of like this…
>
> You can “birth” a Data Tier Application in two places. You can create
> a new project type in Visual Studio where the developer can create the
> database structure, put all of the policies that they want to enforce
> and so on there. The DBA can also right-click a database and make a
> Data Tier Application out of a current structure.
>
> In both cases, **something called a DAC – or Data Application Component**
> – is created. It’s a file with the payload of the the major parts of
> the structure of the database and so on. that’s the **“package”** you use
> to transfer the DTA around.
>
> From there, you right-click in the “Data Tier Application” node in SQL
> Server Management Studio on another Instance and “Deploy” the Data
> Tier Application. It will build the database for you and keep it
> together as a DTA. You can make changes in the “originating” system or
> code, and then “upgrade” the Data Tier Application.
>
> So there you have it. It’s DTA and DAC – but I think you’ll know the
> difference when the time comes to use one…

[This InfoWorld article](https://web.archive.org/web/20140815124506/http://www.infoworld.com/d/data-management/seven-reasons-care-about-sql-server-2008-r2-631?page=0,2) suggests a slight variation on the above, stating that the DACPAC part stands for:

- **D**ata-tier **A**pplication **C**omponent **PAC**kages.

Comment: what's **b** in **bacpac** stands for? backup?

Comment: @KevinXiong I've always assumed so, but I don't think I've ever seen an explanation written down.  The primary purpose of the bacpac is moving a whole database from one place to another, so I think the play on words with "backpack" (with a backpack being something that contains everything when you're travelling) was probably key too.

Answer (score 15):

DAC stands for `Data-tier Application`

PAC stands for `package`

So to my thoughts, DACPAC stands for `Data-tier Application package`

Answer (score 6):

First off:  [read this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210546.aspx).

dacpac is a Data-tier application.  More concretely, it is the file that gets created when you build a SQL Server Database Project.  It contains all of the information necessary to build the db objects specified in your SQL DB project.

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation on what is DACPAC. I asked for the ancronym though. Thanks anyway

Comment: Hey, the guy gave you [at least a source to] exactly the answer, though... "_A **data-tier application (DAC)** is a logical database entity that defines all of the SQL Server objects - such as tables, views, and instance objects, including logins - associated with a user's database. A DAC is a self-contained unit of the entire database model and is portable in an artifact known as a **DAC package, or .dacpac**._" (emphasis mine)