# Why does "DAC" means "Data-tier Application"?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, data-tier-applications, dacpac, dac

The question is quite simple. I have already googled it but I wasn't able to find anything that could relate this terms. I mean, where does the "C" come from?

Does anyone have a hint?

Comment: Data Access Components. See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Data_Access_Components

Comment: Thanks, i'll take a look. BTW, I have found a thread which creator has the same doubt: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20471433

Comment: DAC is data access components. Since they don't actually tell you what it stands for I can only assume it stands for what it has stood for over the past several years.